# Visual Studio stops working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

My visual studio 2013 suddenly keeps saying visual studio has stopped working.
You can`t un instal or repair. I ran it on the safe mode,Admin no result.

Formatted my whole system, installed 2013 express, 2015 community. the problem doesn`t go away.

I don`t konw what else to do?
 any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check that you have the required Frameworks needed to start it.. There might be a hardware compatibility problem.

Comment: Yeah, I have the system requirements. It is interesting that VS 2013 Pro , and VS Express for web have been working in my laptop for about 1 year, no problem. Suddenly, for some reason they are not working any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with process [Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) & Process [Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to diagnose what is happening.

one [sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjKNx41Ubxw) video of issue diagnosis.